# stack two columns in form vs merging on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The goal is to have one form with two columns. When being viewed on a computer monitor two columns appear, but when on mobile, the columns are stacked. I am using  bootstrap. I anticipate I will be using some combination of inline and inline-block, but could use some guidance.

Example form

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Test Form</title>
  </head>
  <style>

    /* ??? */

  </style>
  <body>
  <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <h5>Label 1</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value1" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <h5>Label 2</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value2" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <h5>Label 3</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value3" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <h5>Label 4</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value4" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <h5>Label 5</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value5" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <h5>Label 6</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value6" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    </form>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Desired form out come]

Comment: So you want two columns on mobile? Surely there wouldn't be enough horizontal space to accommodate this?

Comment: what I want is for there to be two columns on a regular sized screen, but on mobile stack the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet

```css
body{margin: 10px}
.m2{background: yellow}
.m1{background: cyan}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 m1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <h5>Label 1</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value1" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <h5>Label 2</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value2" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <h5>Label 3</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value3" class="form-control">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6 m2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <h5>Label 4</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value4" class="form-control">
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <h5>Label 5</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value5" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <h5>Label 6</h5>
            <input type="text" name="value6" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is very easy to achieve using CSS grid. You would need each column on the desktop page in one parent div.
Your HTML should look similar to this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="responsive-column">
        <div class="label">Label 1</div>
        <div class="label">Label 2</div>
        <div class="label">Label 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="responsive-column">
        <div class="label">Label 4</div>
        <div class="label">Label 5</div>
        <div class="label">Label 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS should contain this:

```
#container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2em;
}
@media (max-width: 35rem) and (orientation: portrait){
    #container{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

This will just target portrait mobile devices. For landscape orientation this line should contain something like

```
@media (max-width: 50rem)
```

Although this doesn't use bootstrap at all it should fulfill your needs. You might want to consider a fallback for IE and older Edge versions. Without any type of fallback older Edge and IE will render this form like mobile devices.